# Какие технологии рациональнее всего использовать для backend мобильного PvP игрового проекта?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, backend, gameserver

Какие технологии (ЯП, фреймворки и т.д.) рациональнее всего использовать для backend мобильного PvP игрового проекта?

**Движок:** Unity

**Вид:** PvP, мультиплеер

**Жанр:** Strategy, пошаговая

**Аппаратная платформа:** Mobail

**ОС:** Android и iOS

Под "рациональнее" я подразумеваю: чтобы было меньше "геморроя", меньше "костылей".

#Unity, #Unity3D, #backend, #PvP, #game, #gamedev, #mobail, #Midcore, #Strategy, #Photon, #PUN, #UnityNetworking, #UNet, #unitygamingservices, #UGS, #Node.js

Comment: Какие лучше знаете... а вообще вопрос из разряда что лучше будет закрыть т.к. на него невозможно дать объективный и однозначный ответ. Плюс из Ваших входных данных вообще непонятно что использовать на backende. Какие-то реальные метрики будут (кол-во пользователей в пике, порядки кол-ва объектов и сущностей, которыми придется оперировать и пр.) ?

Comment: @Михаил, Вы правы, я не расписывал полностью все нюансы.
Количество пользователей в пике будет 100 000 (по крайней мере рассчитываем на это в будущем). 

Михаил, можете написать все вопросы, необходимые для ответа на основной вопрос?

Я постараюсь на них ответить.

Я понимаю, что на мой вопрос нельзя дать объективный и однозначный ответ.
Однако, выбор технологий стоит и как-то надо делать этот выбор. 

У нас основной продукт (не игра) на node.js. Однако, пришли к выводу, что на данную игру node.js не лучшее решение.